# I have posted a late/new answer to an old question, and it seems this answer was not subject to review

Tags: support, review-queues, old-questions, late-answers

From what I've understood from the peer review process, new / late answers to old questions should enter the review queue.

I expected this for my answer "[Use powershell for IPC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11766516/what-can-i-use-instead-of-a-unix-pipe-for-inter-process-communication-on-windows/66640388#66640388)" for a 8 years old question, but it seems it was not required this time (my spelling isn't quite good generally...). Are there some cases where new answers to old questions don't require review?

I'm a reader for a long time but a very new contributor (finally having time for that...), so, as it seems there's no question about that, I surely have misunderstood the whole process and I'm sorry for the noise.

Comment: Perhaps it's still in the queue. Except for diamond moderators, the review doesn't show until it's been handled/processed in the queue. I don't think you can be sure until you give it some more time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Late answers to old questions are sent for review if [your reputation is under 50](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266696/can-we-raise-the-bar-for-reputation-for-late-answers-to-bypass-the-review-queue)

> **TL;DR:** As of today (September 29, 2015) the maximum reputation for having an author's late answer enqueued has been raised from 10 to 50.

Your reputation was over 50 at the time you posted the answer so the system trusted you enough not to put your posts into the late answers review queue.

Comment: Congrats on reaching 100K! When was the last time your answer went into the Late Answers Queue?

Comment: I have checked the [help center page about review](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reviews-intro) but there is no mention there of that reputation point. Am i browsing the help center in a wrong way ?

Comment: Thanks @rene, I'm still waiting for the socks and t-shirt. I reached 40 rep the first day I found the site, so never I guess.

Comment: @Zilog80 the help centre covers the basics, not every nuance. You just have to memorise all the meta questions and answers to know how everything works in detail. Or ask a question and one of us will tell you ;-)

Comment: @Zilog80 it is worth keeping an eye on [meta-tag:faq] posts and what they link to (right near the top: Linked questions)